# key colors in a contour plot

Tags: key, label, gnuplot, contour

I'm trying to make a contour plot. With the current script I have got the following figure:
[image: A contour]

Here is the script I used to produce the figure:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
set term png font ",18" enh size 1000,1000
set view map
unset surface
set contour base
set cntrparam level incremental 0.005, 0.02, 0.5
set key at screen 1, 0.9, 0
set rmargin 0.50
#
a=6.3457
set xra[0.:2.60*a]
set yra[0.:1.73*a]
set xtics out nomirror
set ytics axis in offset -4.0,0 nomirror
set label "r (a.u)" at 3.4,-2.2 center
set label "r (a.u)" at -1.7,2.5 rotate by 90 center
set out 'M.1.-1.112.3.888.png'
splot 'M.1.-1.112.3.888.dat' u 1:2:3 w l lw 2 t ''
```

My problem is that I don't like how the colors in the key to indicate the values, they seem to change randomly. Is there a way (gnuplot command) to make the colors change gradually, like the following?
[image]

Comment: Please, share the script of your plot (maybe with some testing data from the data file)!

Comment: @TomSolid I added the script, but sorry I can't add the data since they're just too large! If you like you can change the splot to `splot sin(x) * cos(y)` as to get sample data. My focus is only on the key colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `lintetypes` manually, like:

```
set linetype 1 lc rgb "#B22222"
set linetype 2 lc rgb "#B22233"
set linetype 3 lc rgb "#B22244"
set linetype 4 lc rgb "#B22255"
# ect...
```

OR

```
set style line 1 lc rgb "#B22222"
set style line 2 lc rgb "#B22233"
set style line 3 lc rgb "#B22244"
set style line 4 lc rgb "#B22255"
# ect...
```

Comment: Despite a lot of work to list all the `lintetypes`, it works quite well. Thanks!